# PHP - getElementsByTagName('link') fails even when it exists in Rss feed

Tags: php, rss

I want to parse an RSS feed using PHP. The feed has a tag named `<link>`. But when I use `getElementsByTagName('link')`, It returns the content of tag  and then when I use further `-> childNodes -> nodeValue;` I get no result and an error saying

> Trying to get property of non-object

This is what I am using:

```
$xml="https://cointelegraph.com/rss"

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);

//get elements from "<channel>"
$channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
$channel_title = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

//Problem Causing line
$channel_link = $channel->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
//Problem Causing line

$channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

That rss has these tags:

```
<channel>
<title>Cointelegraph.com News</title>
<atom:link href="https://cointelegraph.com/rss/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
<link>https://cointelegraph.com</link>
......
......
</channel>
```

When I try to get `link`, I instead get `atom:link`

Please also suggest if there is a fast and easy another way to parse RSS in PHP.

Comment: which link are you trying to get hold off, as there are quite a few. For e.g. Do they look like 'https://cointelegraph.com/news/chile-adopts-blockchain-technology-for-national-energy-grid'

Comment: The link that's immediately within channel tag. item tags also have link tags but there is no problem accessing those as there is no atom:link tag within the same parent. Only the Channel tag has both, atom:link and link which causes the GetElementById to return atom:link instead of link. (I don't know why...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get next item

```
$channel->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(1)->nodeValue;
```

and you should get this url if that's the one you are after

```
https://cointelegraph.com
```

### Update

This can be the generic solution you are after.

```
$xml = 'https://cointelegraph.com/rss';
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);
$channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
$links = $channel->getElementsByTagName('link');
$channelLink = '';
for($i=0; $i < $links->length; $i++ ) {
    $link = $channel->getElementsByTagName('link')->item($i);
    if($link->hasAttribute('rel')) {// This can be replaced with what @NigelRen suggested.
        continue;
    }
    $channelLink = $channel->getElementsByTagName('link')->item($i)->nodeValue;
    break;
}

echo $channelLink;
```

Comment: But I also want it to be generic. not all feeds have atom:link that to before link. If I try to use it elsewhere, wouldn't that fail? In my experiment, I am getting the the same result when I use item(0) and item(1) when there is no atom:link tag (in google news rss for example)... I don't know why its the same. but it is the same. In that case your answer still works for me. Thanks

Comment: @KashyapKotak that adds complexity, best to add that to the question. Normally the same rss feed would have the same structure unless they change it.

Comment: @KashyapKotak you can loop through `getElementsByTagName('link')` and if it does not have attribute like `rel' or for that matter any attribute then that is the link you are after since the atom:link has got few attributes. I hope this helps.

Comment: You could simply check each elements `nodeName` which will be either `atom:link` or `link`.

Comment: @NigelRen I agree with you that would be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments from other answer (which should be part of question) you can use XPath...

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);
$xp = new DOMXPath($xmlDoc);

//get elements from "<channel>"
$channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
$channel_title = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

//Problem Causing line
$channel_link = $channel->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(1)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
//Problem Causing line

echo $channel_link.PHP_EOL;

// Use XPath to get first link (not in namespace)
$channel_link = $xp->query("./link", $channel)[0]->nodeValue;
echo $channel_link;
```

The last part uses XPath to find any `<link>` elements in the `<channel>`, but without namespaces involved.

You need to create the `$xp` variable which is the one line near the top.

Comment: Really helpful... Thanks :)